# MYSQL Select IN query using text

Tags: php, mysql

Any quick assistance will be highly appreciated. I've table row in mysql named as mob_categories, now data is being is saved as '|' separated for instance (`cat 1|cat 2|cat 3` and so on. Now i need to get the value from another column in the same table if the input value matches.

for instance if the value is cat 1 i need to select the value from another column is named as `deveice_token` wherever it matches with 'cat 1'

I tried this code but its not working somehow

```
SELECT * from table_name where find_in_set('cat 1',mob_categories) <> 0
```

so i modified a bit with the following code but it works with only numeric value if the value exits in this format in this format (i.e) 1,2,3

```
$userNotification = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * from table_name where 1 IN (mob_categories); ");
```

What's i'm missing specifically?

Comment: You should normalize your schema so you don't have multiple values in a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since data in `mob_categories` are separated by `|` rather than by comma (`,`) so you need to make it compatible for `FIND_IN_SET` first.

So replace all the `|` by comma (`,`) first.

```
SELECT * from table_name where find_in_set('cat 1', REPLACE(mob_categories,'|',',')) > 0
```

Comment: Really? There isn't a better idea?

Comment: If the problem remains as it is then I don't have any better idea than this to solve it in `MySQL` end. If you come up with any better idea then please share . I am looking forward to it. @Strawberry

Comment: Sometimes, we need to reject the premise of the question, and redefine the problem.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks for your prompt response